# Is there any Alternative of SignalR ASP.NET in php (specifically Laravel)

Tags: php, asp.net, laravel, websocket, laravel-5.3

I am working on an api based on laravel version **5.3.**

It's going to be like [Telegram api](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) that can respond to various clients that written with android, iOS or web version(angularjs).

One thing that is an Impartible part of that kind of api is realtime operations.

According to the survey that I did there is a [signalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr) library for **ASP.NET** that makes developing real-time web functionality easy for ASP.NET developers.

SignalR supports Web Sockets, and falls back to other compatible techniques for older browsers like :

- Server-sent Events
- forever frame
- [Long-polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling)

Now I wanted to know that for php and specifically Laravel, Is there a tool that is also easy to write realtime apis?

Comment: I think you should check out Node.js 
1) https://nodejs.org/api/net.html      

2)https://www.codeschool.com/courses/real-time-web-with-node-js

Comment: http://socketo.me/ is what you are looking at

Comment: @FurkanAyık,I have a lot of articles on the web reviewed and of course I am familiar with nodejs and socket-io. but I found that socket-io is supported in A limited number of browsers and does not support in older version of IE for example. in this case SignalR use alternate ways like `Long Polling` , `ForeverFrame`  and etc while node js and socket.io have not this capabilities.right?

Comment: @A.B.Developer I think so now :) It was just alternatives for my view. (I use SignalR too by the way)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laravel offers broadcasting as a feature to send server-side events to clients.
As for clients there is a javascript package which can be implemented

You can read it up in the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/broadcasting#installing-laravel-echo)

> Laravel Echo is a JavaScript library that makes it painless to subscribe to channels and listen for events broadcast by Laravel. You may install Echo via the NPM package manager.

Comment: Echo is written based on `Vue-js` while my front-end library is angular js. Do you think `Echo` is appropriate in this case?

Comment: do you not have any ideas ?

Comment: Echo itself can be used with whatever Javascript Library/Framework you like :) it is not dependend on vuejs

Answer (score 0):

you can use socket.io with Redis for angular client and Laravel backend

publish messages on redis from Laravel -> subscribe to redis in a node server and emit messages to socket io -> get messages using socket.io in angular client

you may need to configure reverse proxy in your apache virtual host configuration to node server for all ws requests